# Created columns are not showing in custom new form(Add) page in SharePoint 2013 List?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, site-column, splist-custom-newform

I created a New Custom page in the list and set it as default, Before that, I enabled the 
**Allow management of content types? checkbox** and created a column by checking **Add to all content types** check box.

But it not showing in a custom page, It showing in Default newform.aspx. I don't understand why? Correct me If I am missing anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @suriya , what do you mean with "But it not showing in a custom page, It showing in Default newform.aspx" Do you mean the default columns?

Comment: Hi @Qassas I mean I created a new page in list and set it as default by using sharepoint designer. In default new form page newly added column are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default list forms are using the [`ListFormWebPart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listformwebpart.aspx) class.

When you create a new list form, the new one is using the [`DataFormWebPart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.aspx) class, which means you have to manually specify which fields appear on the form by editing the form in SharePoint Designer.

You can check the differences yourself by editing the forms in Advanced Mode in SharePoint Designer and looking between the `WebPartPages` tags.

If you do not want to manually edit the fields on the new form, you can convert it to use the ListFormWebPart class. To do this follow the steps below:

- Copy the `WebPartPages` tags and everything in-between them from the default NewForm and paste it over the `WebPartPages` tags in the new NewForm.
- Open up a website that can generate a new GUID (e.g. [https://www.guidgen.com](https://www.guidgen.com/))
- Copy the new GUID and paste it in the following places on the new NewForm:

  - the value of the `__WebPartId` attribute of the `WebPartPages` tag
  - between the `ID` tags after the `g_` bit. **MAKE SURE** to replace the hyphens of the GUID with underscores.